# Probability of compositions/ Dependency of standard deviation on sample size

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, standard-deviation

I have following problem.
Given is a 2 component solution with components A and B=1-A.

I now want to know the probability of certain compositions for a given mean composition. So if the mean composition is 50/50, how is the probability for your sample to be 90/10?

So obviously, this is a normal distribution where the expectation value is the mean composition $\mu=\frac{A}{1-A}$. The  problem is the standard deviation. $\sigma$ has to be a function of A as well, since the normal distribution is getting more narrow the closer A  gets so 0 or 1, because if A is 1 or 0 the probability to pick B is equal 0 or respectively equal 1.

So i didn't know how to get to this analytically, but with brute force I found that $\sigma=f(mean(A))$ must somehow be described by the function of an ellipsoid, with its center at A=0.5.

So I wanted to fit that function, when I came to the problem, that $\sigma$ is not only a function of mean(A), but also depends on my sample size N. The larger the sample, the smaller $\sigma$...

So, is there somehow an analytical solution to get $\sigma=f(mean(A),N)$?

Many thanks in advance

Best regards Marc

EDIT: Code to compare normal approximation to binomial and brute force
[image]

close all

cmp=0.5;  mean composition

draws=50;  numbers of balls per draw

var=draws cmp (1-cmp);  varianz

x=linspace(0,1,101);

y=1/sqrt(var*2*pi)*exp(-0.5*(x-cmp).^2/var);  normal distribution to binomial distribution

figure
subplot(1,2,1)

plot(x,y,'r-')

same but brute force with 10000 draws each 50 balls
subplot(1,2,2)
cmp=0.5;
draws=50;

histogram(sum(rand(draws,10000)>cmp,1)/draws,[0:0.01:1])

Comment: How are you modeling your solution?  Are you thinking of it as equivalent to drawing balls from a mix in which half are black and half are white?  But in that analogy, the number of balls you draw is critical. If you draw only one, it is guaranteed to be monochromatic.  If you draw three, it could be monochromatic...but really not if you draw thousands.  In your situation, what is the analog of the number of balls?

Comment: The analogy matters.  If you regard water as two parts H to one part O, then your sample is "guaranteed" to respect that ratio.  But a different model would yield different statistics.

Comment: Yeah, its like drawing black and white balls from an infinity large pool of balls.
Its actually about statistical thermodynamics and the question is, about the probabilities of the composition of nuclei for precipitations. So the overall pool wold be all the atoms of elements A and B, and a typical sample size (atoms in a critical nucleus) would range from like 20- ~100

Comment: So, the analogy for the number of balls is the number of atoms you draw?  Pretty strict analogy, then.

Comment: yeah, is 100% analogy to the balls in to pool i would guess

Comment: If the sample is small compared to the total, you can assume independence as an approximation, so you just have a routine binomial distribution.  If you can't assume that the sample is small, then you need to work with binomial coefficients, which will be unpleasant since the numbers are so huge. I'll bet there are standard models out there that approximate this well.  Some sort of brownian bridge...for small samples, the mean behaves like the problem were binomial, but for larger ones the mean gets locked in.

Comment: For small samples, I'd just take the normal approximation.  Mean as you say, and variance equal to $N\times p\times (1-p)$ (where $p$ is the probability of one of the two outcomes...in your case , $p=.5$).  That works fine if you can assume independence.  Clearly fails if the sample gets large.

Comment: Guess I am looking for that approximation model... ad what the definition of small is. I guess it comes to the question, how many atoms do I need, to call them a particle and not a bunch of atoms... So from observations I know that these nuclei can have sizes as <1nm. thats why estimate the sample size to be somewhere in this region of lets say 50 atoms/balls

Comment: I mean I know that I could calculate is with the permutations for small samples and for latrger onces I can fit the brude force results... but this the dependency lloks like an ellipsoid, I just think there must be a analytical description

Comment: 50 atoms is a small sample, independence will hold.  It's "brute" force, by the way.  The expression, I mean.  And the normal approximation to the binomial distribution will work just fine.

Comment: Edited original post to show a comprison betwwen normal appriximation to binomial and a brute fore approach with 10k samples each 50 balls.
So I either misunderstood your intention, our the approximation does not hold

Comment: for varianz=(p*(1-p))/N instead ofvarianz=sqrt(p*(1-p)*p) its perfect

Comment: I don't understand.  Assuming independence, the variance is what I said, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for instance.  And I was assuming that your total pool had many, many more than $50$ atoms so assuming independence was safe.  Of course if the total pool is small, then you can't use this.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question.  If all you want are estimates of the mean and variance, you can just use [Sample Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)).  I thought you wanted detailed information on the distribution, which is harder to come by.